# C++ reference to the class

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ and I have a project where one of the classes have a reference to another class in the form that I will mention below. I just want to understand what reference to a class actually mean. Sorry, I am not going to post my program but rather just gonna provide an example, because I want to actually understand what reference to a class means instead of someone showing how to fix my code.

so lets say I have two classes Class_1 and Class_2. I need to call Class_1 from Class_2 by passing two arguments to Class_1`s constructor.

This is how Class_1 constructor looks like in a Class_1 cpp file

```
Class_1::Class_1(int nRows, int nCols)
{
    m_rows=nRows;
    m_cols=nCols;
    m_numSnakesDied=0;
    display();

}
```

It is a requirement for me to declare Class_2 in Class_1 header file in a following way

```
Class_1& class_1();
```

As you can see, I need to acquire nRows and nCols from Class_1 when it callls Class_2. The problem is that I don't understand what this Class_1& class_1(); actually means, and I am not sure how to initialize Class_1`s constructor from Class_2`s cpp file.

Sorry if my explanation is crappy, English is a third language to me.

Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your problem is. You are saying `Class_1` but the posted code uses `History`. Perhaps posting code that clearly points out the problem will help.

Comment: I think the problem is either referring to friends or to what class references mean? I'm not quite sure either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of unclear for your question.

You can use something like:

```
Class_1 a; // a is an instance of Class_1
Class_1& b = a; // b is a reference to an instance of Class_1 (a)
```

so that a and b are exactly the same object.

If you need arguments for constructor:

```
Class_1 c(2, 3); // c is an instance of Class_1.
                 // this will initialize c with nRows = 2 and nCols = 3
Class_1& d = c;  // d is a reference to an instance of Class_1 (c)
```

As for your sample code:

```
Class_1& class_1();
```

It means class_1 is a function which returns a reference to an instance of Class_1. So maybe you want to implement something like:

```
Class_2 {
public:
    Class_1& class_1() {
        return a; // return a reference to an instance of Class_1 (a)
    }
private:
    Class_1 a; // an instance of Class_1
}
```

I suggest you to post more complete code so that we can help.
Otherwise we are just guessing what's your problem.

**Edit**
Remove the example of reference to a temporary because it's not permitted.

Comment: `Class_1& e = Class_1(4, 5);` is not possible. A reference to non-const cannot refer to a temporary.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation at the very end is exactly what I was asking, sorry for inclearness. What I end up doing is I declared History m_history in private of Class_1 and then used history to return refference to m_history.